# Whats the fetch equivalent for curl -k (--insecure) option when making http/s request

Tags: reactjs, curl

I am using react app , where i need to call a https post method .Using curl the same post method throws me the error

curl: (60) Peer's Certificate issuer is not recognized.

i overcome this by using the curl k (--insecure) option, and it works.

I now want to implement using fetch in my react code, how to get "-insecure" mode equivalent in fetch api (or any other api)

```
let username = '***';
let password = '***';

let headers = new Headers();
headers.set('Authorization', 'Basic ' + btoa(username + ":" + password));
headers.set('Jenkins-Crumb', '"***"');

headers.set('Connection', 'keep-alive');
headers.set('Accept', '*/*');
headers.set('Content-Length', '0');


                    fetch('https://IP:443/jenkins/view/ASAP/job/ASAP_WEBLOGIC_SERVER_RESTART_PIPLELINE/lastBuild/logText/progressiveText?start=0', {
                    method: 'GET',
                    mode: 'cors',

                    headers: headers
                    ,
                    body: 
                    JSON.stringify(this.props.fields)
                  })
                    .then(results => results.json())
                    .then(json => {
                      this.setState({
                        isLoaded: true,
                        data: json
                      })
                    });
                }
```

any help is appreciated!!

Comment: no experience with `react`, but don't you want `method: 'POST'` ? Good luck.

Comment: I don't have an answer but I am running into similar issue - want to find a way to do equivalent of curl -k

Comment: it worked by used Axios https with insecure mode instead of fetch api. You can check if that works for you. User965692